# How can I get a Chatango chat to open in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I cannot seem to get a Chatango chat to open in an Android WebView. I can get the chat to open in the stock Android browser and in the android Chrome browser, but not in a WebView. Does anybody know how I can resolve this? My code is as follows:

```
public void chat()
{
    WebView chat = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.chatView);
    chat.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    chat.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    chat.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    chat.loadUrl("http://lgthesandbox.chatango.com/");
    chat.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

I know my code is correct because I can get other URL's to load in the WebView, but the Chatango chat just refuses to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Chatango is using the Flash player. This is no longer supported on Android and as of KitKat it's not possible for Flash to play in WebView.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add:

```
chat.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Tested and working.

Comment: All I see is "This version is not available in your current browser. Download Chrome for Android".